# null! (non-null assertion operator after null)

Tags: typescript

I stumbled upon this `null!` when learning React with TypeScript.

```js
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null!);
```

I don't know why the `!` is necessary or what it is doing.

I come from Dart background and if I do this in Dart, it will throw an error. I assume it is similar but works differently from the Dart one.

Comment: Evidently you know it's a non-null assertion, which in that case is a lie. You want to know why it's necessary, so: what happens if you remove it?

Comment: You better define it as `const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);`

Comment: `!` does not guarantee anything during runtime, it's just used to force typescript to think that value is not null. And I don't think that is even required here, `useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)` should work fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBK6BmcC+cOUEIcA5FOgIYDGM5A3AFDO0QB2q8wHYyMbHgC8KDEIA8ACQAqAWQAyAST4CAogBt0IdBxgA+ABQdkGjQEoWQA

Comment: TypeScript sometimes uses the term "assertion" differently from how you might expect; the non-null assertion operator doesn't do anything at runtime, it's just a way of telling the compiler that a value isn't null. (See [https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-).) In this case, it's *lying* to the compiler . . . which is basically never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` after anything in TypeScript is generally something that you should avoid. You'll see most general linting rules throw a warning against using it.

It is used to force TypeScript to think that the value is not `null`. When the developer is so confident that this value will not be `null` or `undefined` when writing their code, they will use the `!` operator.

Generally, it's better to just place a guard statement higher up in your code if something could potentially be `null`/`undefined` or use optional chaining instead like this: `myPotentiallyUndefinedObject?.name || 'fallback'`.

In your specific question about using `null!`, that just makes zero sense to use because you shouldn't be confidently saying that `null` will never be `null` because it's clearly `null`.

Just say `const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);` without the `!` and let TypeScript know that the value could be `null`. Then TypeScript will be much nicer to work with in the rest of your component.